# Save a gensim LDA model to s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gensim

I've got an LDA model through using gensim. I can save it locally:

```
ldamodel.save('models/lda/lda.model')
```

This results in four files in the specified place:

```
lda.model
lda.model.expElogbeta.npy
lda.model.id2word
lda.model.state
```

Loading them back is as simple as

```
ldamodel =  models.LdaModel.load('models/lda/lda.model')
```

However, I want this model to be saved on s3. I can work out how to save individual bits, for example:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file('models/lda/lda.model', 'bucket-name', 'lda.model')
```

But I can't work out how to actually meaningfully read them back in so they will function as expected as a coherent model. So the idea being that somebody other than me could take the files from s3 and use them as a model in Python.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why won't you implement a class that takes into account the logical relationship of the separate files comprising the model and treat it as one?

e.g.

```
class LdaModel:
   def __init__(self, lda_local_path, s3bucket_name, s3bucket_obj_prefix):
       self.local_path = lda_local_path
       self.s3bucket = s3bucket_name
       self.s3bucket_obj_pre = s3bucket_obj_prefix

    def upload(self):
        for fl in os.listdir(self.local_path):
            fl_local = os.path.join(self.local_path, fl)
            s3.meta.client.upload_file(fl_local, self.s3bucket, self.s3bucket_obj_pre + '__' + fl_local)

    def download(self): 
        ...
```

(I left out `download` method for you to implemented by analogy to the `upload` one).

Another approach is to implement a zip-wrapper that will compress the 4 files and store them as one in S3.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I am quite new to Python but this helped.